# How to properly reset an object item

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm currently working on something that requires me to put the value of an input field as an object item.

```
var test = {
    item1:{
        subitem1: "", <------- This is the one I'm trying to fill
        subitem2: "",
        subitem3: "",
        subitem4: ""
    }
};
```

This value gets filled when the input field `#thecontent` changes

```
$('.wrapper').on('change', '#thecontent', function(){
    var theContent = $(this).val();
    test.item1.subitem1 = theContent;
});
```

Now, the input text field is only visible after I check an input checkbox `#checkit`

```
if(this.checked) {
    $('#thecontent').show();
}
```

If the checkbox is unchecked however, not only does the input field disapear, but the object item also needs to be reset. 
Currently I'm doing this as following:

```
else{
    $('#thecontent').hide();        
    //This part probably needs to be reset in a different way
    test.item1.subitem1 = "";
}
```

**This works, HOWEVER, if I try to fill the object item again after I reset it once, it doesn't fill it with the new value anymore.**

How do I go about resetting a value inside an object so I can fill it again later on?

To conclude:

- Check box ->
- enter "this is a value" in the input box ->
- Click "test it" ->
- subitem1 is populated with "this is a value" in console ->
- Uncheck the box to reset the Object ->
- Check the box again ->
- enter "This is a different value" ->
- Click "test it" ->
- See empty subitem1  while i expected "This is a different value" in console.

What did I miss?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dqmkvrr/3/)**

Comment: it seems to be working for me...

Comment: Really? What browser? Firefox keeps returning an empty value after I reset it once.

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, Safari all work. After all your steps, I click "{item1: Object}" in the console, and there's "a different value" as expected.

Comment: Think it has something to do with the console settings, when I stringify and alert it, it shows as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend on removing the text from the input when hiding it, one solution is to simply trigger a "change" programmatically:

```
if(this.checked) {
    $('#thecontent').show().trigger("change");
}
```

See Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2dqmkvrr/4/